# parent div's width larger than children's width in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have a strange issue in Firefox.

I have a div with height defined in constant px value, and there is an img element within that. I have no problem with this setup in chrome, but in firefox parent div's width turns out to be larger than the img in it.

This is the html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imageHolder">
        <img src='dasource'>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 900px;
}

.imageHolder {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imageHolder img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/6

As explained in this fiddle, in firefox, the parent div turns out to be larger than the image in it.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: The difference in those two fiddles has nothing to do with the javascript.  One has `overflow: hidden`, the other does not.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the difference between firefox and chrome still persists. I have updated the question to reflect this change

Comment: This does look like a bug in FF to me.  For some reason `overflow: hidden` is causing the parent div to use the width of the unscaled image rather than post-scaling.  http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/7/  Do you need that `overflow: hidden`?  Here is a minimal version with the unneeded bits removed to reproduce the issue minimally  http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/11/ - not sure if it helps... but now it works as it should (except bottom)... when explicit height is set to wrapper - 500px - then all is fine. :)

Comment: @nevermind making the height 500px means the image no longer has to scale, preventing the issue entirely since the image is also 500px high.

Comment: As James suggested, when I remove that overflow: hidden, it works as expected. I will go with removing that, cause I do not actually need that in my case. But I don't know how to prevent this issue if you need that overflow:hidden. James if you post your comment as an answer I can accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does look like a bug in Firefox to me. For some reason `overflow: hidden` is causing the parent `div` to use the width of the unscaled image rather than post-scaling.

http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/8

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <img src='http://placehold.it/650x650' />
<div>
```

```
.imageHolder {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imageHolder img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

In this stripped down example, you can clearly see the issue.  The image is originally `650px` wide, rescaled based on height, it becomes `400px` wide.  The parent however, remains `650px` wide.

If you do not need the `overflow: hidden` simply removing that fixes the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/12/

**EDIT:**  [Firefox bugzilla ticket for this issue.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=829958)

Comment: Apparently giving a pixel value instead of percent doesn't cause the bug.

Comment: 500px? Isn't it 450px? Actually, i am sure that 450px is in question - because 50% of 900px - (wrapper) is in question?

Comment: @nevermind Yes, due to the `max-width` it was shrunk to 450.  I've updated with a stripped down fiddle to better illustrate the actual issue.

Comment: If you need to keep overflow: hidden here, which I later found out that I needed, you can wrap the imageHolder div with another parent div, and give it overflow: hidden. You can test this scenario in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXudn/14/